# Writing methods and constructors

Tags: class, methods, constructor

OK, i need someone to explain to me where to start on this project.

First I need to overload the constructor by adding a default (no-args) constructor to *Person* that defines an object to have the name "N/A" and an id of -1.

Then i need to add a setter method named reset that can be used to reset the two private instance variables of this class to two values passed in as parameters.

Then I need to add a getter method named getName and getId that can be used to retrieve these two private variables

Here is the code:

```
public class Person
{
private String name;
private int    id;
private static int personCount = 0;

// constructor
public Person(String pname)
{
name = pname;
personCount++;
id = 100 + personCount;
}



public String  toString()
{
 return "name: " + name + "  id: " + id
  + "  (Person count: " + personCount + ")";
}

// static/class method
public static int getCount()
{
  return personCount;
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class StaticTest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
{
    Person tom = new Person("Tom Jones");
    System.out.println("Person.getCount(): " + Person.getCount());
    System.out.println(tom);
    System.out.println();

    Person sue = new Person("Susan Top");
    System.out.println("Person.getCount(): " + Person.getCount());
    System.out.println(sue);
    System.out.println("sue.getCount(): " + sue.getCount());
    System.out.println();

    Person fred = new Person("Fred Shoe");
    System.out.println("Person.getCount(): " + Person.getCount());
    System.out.println(fred);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("tom.getCount(): " + tom.getCount());
    System.out.println("sue.getCount(): " + sue.getCount());
    System.out.println("fred.getCount(): " + fred.getCount());
}
}
```

I'm not exactly sure where to start and I don't want just the answer. I'm looking for someone to explain this clearly.

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)'s a good place to start :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First I need to overload the constructor by adding a default (no-args) constructor to Person that defines an object to have the name "N/A" and an id of -1.*

Read about constructors [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

The Person class already contains a ctor that takes 1 argument. What you need to do is create a "default ctor" which is typically a ctor w/out any parameters.

Example:

```
class x
{
   // ctor w/ parameter
   //
   x(int a)
   {
      // logic here
   }

   // default ctor (contains no parameter)
   //
   x()
   {
     // logic here
   }
}
```

*Then i need to add a setter method named reset that can be used to reset the two private instance variables of this class to two values passed in as parameters.*

Setter methods are used to "encapsulate" member variables by "setting" their value via public function. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html).

Example:

```
class x
{
   private int _number;

   // Setter, used to set the value of '_number'
   //
   public void setNumber(int value)
   {
     _number = value; 
   }
}
```

*Then I need to add a getter method named getName and getId that can be used to retrieve these two private variables*

Getters do the opposite. Instead of "setting" the value of a private member variable, they are used to "get" the value from the member variable.

Example:

```
class x
{
   private int _number;

   // Getter, used to return the value of _number
   //
   public int getNumber()
   {
      return _number;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend consulting the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), which should be very helpful here. For example, there is a section on [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) which details how they work, even giving an example of a no-argument form:

> Although `Bicycle` only has one constructor, it could have others, including a no-argument constructor:
>
> ```
> public Bicycle() {
>     gear = 1;
>     cadence = 10;
>     speed = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> `Bicycle yourBike = new Bicycle();` invokes the no-argument constructor to create a new `Bicycle` object called `yourBike`.

Similarly, there are sections dedicated to [defining methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [passing information to them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). There's even a section on [returning values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) from your method.

Read the above and you should be able to complete your homework :-)